# Pass templated class to templated function

Tags: c++, function, class, templates, non-type

I have a non-type templated class:

```
template<int N> class MyClass; // prototype
```

And a generic template function:

```
template<class T> Parameters validParams(); // prototype
```

What is the correct syntax to use a non-type templated class in a templated function? If I don't use a templated class, then the correct syntax is:

```
template<> Parameters validParams<MyClass>(); // prototype
```

I've looked around a bit to try to figure out what the syntax should be here, any help is appreciated! It would make the most sense to me if it were the following, but it's not...

```
template<> Parameters validParams<MyClass<int>>();
```

With this code I get the following error:

> ```
> expected a constant of size 'int', got 'int'
> ```

Comment: By the way, with the MyClass<int> syntax that I would guess, I get an error like "expected a constant of size 'int', got 'int'"

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> template<> Parameters validParams<MyClass<int>>();
> ```

Should be something like

```
template<> Parameters validParams<MyClass<42>>();
                                       // ^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_arguments)

`MyClass<int>` is not a type (`MyClass<42>`, for example, is), while the function expects a name of a type (class) as a parameter. For it to be able to take a *template* as its *template parameter*, the syntax must be following:

```
template<template<typename> class T> Parameters validParams();
```

Answer (score 0):

`MyClass` is a class templates whose template parameter is a value, not a type.

`MyClass<0>` *is* a valid instantiation of that template that results in a class.
`MyClass<int>` *is not* a valid instantiation of that template.

Hence, the line

```
template<> Parameters validParams<MyClass<int>>();
```

is not valid. A valid use will be:

```
template<> Parameters validParams<MyClass<0>>();
```

or

```
template<> Parameters validParams<MyClass<X>>();
```

as long as `X` is a compile time constant.